# About Any the wiser

Tags: idioms

> If you don't tell them, nobody will be any the wiser. (Cited from OLD)

I want to know whether 'any' modifies 'the wiser' or not.
I think that it does, because the wiser means one of one wiser, thus any the wiser means 'any one of one wiser', so any can be 'determiner' in this way, it is actually 'adverb' though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I think you are on the wrong track.

The idiom is *any the X-er* (where X can be certain adjectives or adverbs) means *to any degree X-er*. It is not particularly common, and *any the wiser* seems to be by far the most common example.

Examples (from the iWeb corpus):

> But would they be any the happier for that? (*Brave New World* by Aldous Huxley, 1932)
>
> would the world be any the better? (*The Republic* by Plato, tr. Benjamin Jowett, Book X)
>
> Patients do not suffer any the less for being unable to make treatment decisions (*Near death Experiences and the Afterlife*, 2018)

The adjective is just an adjective, not a nominalised adjective.

Comment: The answer that was chosen is wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "any one of one wiser." That doesn't make sense to me.

But I believe that you are correct that ***any*** modifies ***the wiser [people]***. I believe the idiom also omits "of," so I think the sentence actually means:

> If you don't tell them, nobody will be ***any [of] the wiser [people]***.

There's a similar idiom ***none the wiser***, which I would interpret as:

> If you don't tell them, they will be ***none [of] the wiser [people]***.

Comment: I thought that  "any one of one group of wiser people " equals "any the wiser" or "any of the wiser people.

Comment: Ah, OK, I guess that's correct: "anyone of a group of wiser people." You don't have to get too bogged down with a word-for-word definition here. It's good to understand how the idiom is constructed, but I think most native speakers would have trouble explaining it. As long as you know what it means and how to use it correctly, that's the important thing.

Comment: I couldn't agree more to your advice, but as a foreigner I think it is needed to understand how the meaning is read so by native speakers.

Comment: Maybe the idiom is `( ) the wiser`. After viewing several basic sources and still lacking a definitive answer to my own confusion, I deduced there are multiple idioms.

Comment: But it isn't any of the wiser. It's idiomatic: any the wiser, any the richer, any of the poorer.